# Splitting an input file into separate numbers and then using them as input into program

Tags: c, file, input, strtok, split

I am using codeblocks and have hit a wall, I want to get two numbers from a .txt file and use assign them to different constants.

Say in the input .txt file there is 10,20 I want to make it that a=10 and b=20, and then continue to use these numbers to do further calculations.

In the past I have split up a string from a file by using 'strtok' with (" ,:") being the delimiterising string.

```
FILE *fp; char s[1000];
fp=fopen("chris.txt","r"); // opens the file


if (!fp) return 1;
while (fgets(s,1000,fp)!=NULL); //makes the stuff inside the file defined as string s


char*pch;printf("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",s);
pch = strtok (s,",");
while (pch !=NULL)
{
printf ("%s\n",pch);
pch= strtok(NULL," ,0.");
}
```

I am thinking I could follow a similar way, but somehow assign the different numbers to different constants. Any thoughts as to how to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

```
int a, b;

if (sscanf(s, "%d,%d", &a, &b) != 2) {
    // Error, the format was not "<int>,<int>" 
}
```

You can even use `scanf` to directly read from the file

```
if (fscanf(fp, "%d,%d", &a, &b) != 2) {
```

Comment: thanks for that, only a slight problem that they're not single digits, is there a way of making it read in say 10 and 20?

Comment: @chemistryprograms `%d` does not scan for single digits, `%d` means "scan for ints" which means "read as many digits until the first non digit character is found". It will work just fine with `10,20`, just give it a try. It will only fail if numbers are bigger than what an `int` can hold. In that case you can use `%ld` to scan a `long` value and `%lld` to scan `long long` value (of course, a and b will have to be of type `long` or `long long` in these cases). Use `%u`, `%lu` and `%llu` for `unsigned`, `unsigned long` and `unsigned long long`.

Comment: @chemistryprograms Maybe you assumed incorrectly that `%d` is an abbreviation for `digit`, which is not the case. The `d` is an abbreviation of `decimal` and a decimal is a number in the base 10 (Decimal) system. This is contrary to `%x` and `%o`, which parse numbers in the base 16 (heX) or base 8 (Octal) system.

Answer (score 0):

Using the wxWidgets framework I normally use [wxTextInputStream](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxtextinputstream.html) to perform these kind of tasks. Follow the link to see an example.

If [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) is not your thing, it may give you some ideas.

Comment: I didn't notice this wasn't a C++ question. My fault.